# Can't make regex to match URL in redirect rule in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following url:

> http://mysite.com/dir/someone-else%E2%80%99s-black-tie/

I want my htaccess to redirect that to:

> http://mysite.com/dir/someone-elses-black-tie/

How can accomplish that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{SERVER_PORT}s ^(.*):(443(s)|\d+s)$
RewriteRule ^/?(dir/someone-else).+(s-black-tie/?)$ http%3://%1/$1$2 [R=301,L]
```